# Deployment order of WAR file specified using deployment descriptor

Tags: web-applications, jetty, war, jgroups

I using deployment descriptor XML file to deploy WAR file, say 'sample.war'. I have also deployed WAR file sin webapps. Does the 'sample.war' always deployed before other WARs in webapps?

Answer (score 1):

Deployment order is FileSystem dependent.

There is no provisions in the servlet spec to dictate the webapp loading order.
Having webapps depend on each other directly like that is highly discouraged.

Common classes or functionality are typically shared via the server classloader and JNDI.

Comment: Thank you. In my application, I use jar file for common functionalities as singleton. This jar must be invoked by only one War, say 'sample.War' though jar instance is present in all the war files. Hence 'sample.war' must be initiated before any other war files. 

Since in Jetty, each web application has its own class loader, how can server class loader be used?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: "each web application has its own class loader" - this is the default behavior for all Servlet spec containers (jetty, tomcat, jboss, weblogic, etc..).  That concept/behavior is mandated by the spec.

Comment: Thank you. My need is, I have some common functionalities which needs to be shared across all the wars. Currently I define this as common jar and refer to it using manifest file.Which method is preferred? Common jar or server class loader? I'm using Jetty server. Is there any way to make this server independent though intended is jetty. Thanks in advance

Comment: From "Common classes or functionality are typically shared via the server classloader and JNDI." Is it possible to create class loader for WAR file instead of single .class file?

Comment: Custom ClassLoader for WAR files is unsupported.   Have you considered not using WARs entirely?  You could use embedded-jetty, without war files, and setup the server in the strange way you are attempting.   Otherwise, if WAR files are a requirement, then you should abandon the whole access of the common object via java references, and access it via a network communication like HTTP, or WebSocket, or REST (like thousands of other projects do today)

Comment: War file is requirement. I'm using JGroups to establish cluster. This cluster is used by several services that is deployed as war. Here the apps use observer pattern. Cluster is subject and other services are observers. Each services i.e war files exposes REST to communicate with outer world. But the communication between cluster app and other wars cannot use REST as they need to share singleton object observer (I guess different wars cannot follow observer pattern) and hence I'm looking for methods of communication. I currently use cluster as common jar.Looking other methods b4 implementation

Comment: JGroups does not need or use a singleton behavior, classloader tricks, or funky war load order requirements.  JGroups operates entirely via RPC communications (aka network communications).  Each webapp will just be another node on your JGroups environment, no webapp will be master.

Comment: Each webapp should not be a separate node. Each device must be a separate node. Each service say s1 and s2 which will be deployed in all the servers should use same Jgroups channel. Hence war communication is required. Thanks in advance

Comment: The reason for ordering is that I have a master war ( which just initiates Jgroups and contains few REST services) which must deployed and initiate cluster before any other war files (any application that uses Jgroups for communication) other war files shouldn't initiate Jgroups hence I require master war to load before any other war.

Comment: Overview: My current application have Jgroups and application logic say service 1 together in a war file. Now if another new service say service 2 is added that will be in tha same war file. These two services must use same Jgroups. Instead of that, now trying to separate Jgroups and services. Jgroups will run independently of services. Since my Jgroups implementation also contains REST call, I packed this into a war say jWar and core functionalities into a jar. Now this jar will be be initialized thru init of jWar and REST will be exposed. Other services must communicate with jar file

Comment: This is now out of scope of the original question, as it has delved into jgroups installation and configuration.  You might have more luck having a specific [tag:jgroups] narrowed question on how to install jgroups on a servlet engine with multiple webapps, don't assume that it must be done a specific way, asking specific questions on how to bend/break specs to fit this assumption will just lead to frustration.

Comment: Thank you so much. Since I don't want to add much details I narrowed down my original question, which I'm curious to know (might be helpful ) This has many aspects to look into and that's why I kept original question precise and should not confuse the ones who views it. Thanks :-)